# Webforms in excel instead of e-mail

Tags: excel, email, forms

A client of mine asked me if i can find a solution for this problem.
His website (still a WIP) http://welkommagazine.nl/luuk/ has a form. The form obviously uses a sendmail script to send the form to e-mail. From thereon he manually copy/pastes all the submissions to excel.

What he wants is that the forms online automaticcaly are added to an excel document to save him a lot of work.

Now i am not a programmer, but a designer.. I think this can be done, but i have absolutely no clue how. I googled alot for it and the only thing i found was a dreamweaverplugin.

Is there a way to do this, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. I wrote a PHP code snippet which actually stores the fields comma seperated in a CSV file and sends an email to a desired adress with the filled in fields.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ 
   $pakket = $_POST['pakket']; 
   $extragidsen = $_POST['extragidsen']; 
   $naambedrijf = $_POST['naambedrijf']; 
   $err = ''; 

   if(trim($pakket)==''){ 
      $err .= '-Please enter a name
'; 
   } 
   if(empty($extragidsen)){ 
      $err .= '-Please enter an email address'; 
   } 
   if(strlen($naambedrijf)==0){ 
      $err .= '-Please enter a comment
'; 
   } 

   if($err!=''){ 
      echo $err; 
   } 
   else{ 
      $filename = 'file.csv'; 
      $somecontent = $pakket . ',' . $extragidsen . ',' . $naambedrijf . "\n"; 

      // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first. 
      if (is_writable($filename)) { 

         // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode. 
         // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence 
         // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it. 
         if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) { 
             echo "Cannot open file ($filename)"; 
             exit; 
         } 

         // Write $somecontent to our opened file. 
         if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) { 
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)"; 
            exit; 
         } 

        //--------------------------Set these paramaters--------------------------

        // Subject of email sent to you.
        $subject = 'Inschrijving welkom'; 

        // Your email address. This is where the form information will be sent. 
        $emailadd = 'luuk@luukratief.com'; 


        // Where to redirect after form is processed. 
        $url = 'http://www.google.com'; 

        // Makes all fields required. If set to '1' no field can not be empty. If set to '0' any or all fields can be empty.
        $req = '0'; 

        // --------------------------Do not edit below this line--------------------------
        $text = "Results from form:\n\n"; 
        $space = ' ';
        $line = '
        ';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
        if ($req == '1')
        {
        if ($value == '')
        {echo "$key is empty";die;}
        }
        $j = strlen($key);
        if ($j >= 20)
        {echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";die;}
        $j = 20 - $j;
        for ($i = 1; $i ';
         fclose($handle); 

      } else { 
         echo "The file $filename is not writable"; 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Maybe the code aint that clean as it can be, but eh it works.
Feel free to clean up the code if you want to :)

I guessed I would answer this myself for the community...
BTW u need to set "write" rights to "file.csv" 
cheers

Answer (score 2):

Not a programmer's response, but...
I think an easy solution is to use Google docs. You can set-up a Google Spreadsheet and associate a form to it. Whenever a user fills the form , his data is added to the spreadsheet.
Your client may download that anytime.
There are some other providers on the market, some free, some not. E.g: wufoo.com

Comment: not exactly the answer i was looking for, but i will look into it. thanks!